# Find object by property in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I have problem with get string in JSON data. Format as below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "id": "David",
    "last": "25"
  },
  {
    "id": "John",
    "last": "30"
  }
]
```

Sometime it changes position together, `John` from 3rd place go to 2nd place:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
    "name": "David",
    "age": "25"
  }
]
```

If i use `data[3].age` to get `John`'s age, and data change position, I will get `David`'s age.

Is there any method I can use to find the object with `name` `David` and get the `age` value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: `data[3].age` will give you an index error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **[`array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** method as,

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
    "name": "David",
    "age": "25"
  }
];

//Here you are passing the parameter name and getting the age 
//Find will get you the first matching object
var result = myArray.find(t=>t.name ==='John').age;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Work like charm. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

It's better to use [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (better browser support)

```
myArray.filter(function(el){return el.name == "John"})[0].age
```

Comment: Although `Array.filter` has better browser support than `Array.find`, I'd like to point out that `find` will return when it finds a match, whereas `filter` will go through every item in the array. So, it will perform worse if the array is large. In those cases, regular `for` loop with `break` statements should be preferred.